# context problem in flutter "Undefined name 'context'"

Tags: flutter, dart

Is someone able to explain to me why 'context' in there is undefined? i Watched like 5 videos about BuildContext and i still don't understand it. Yes i'm beginner with dart

```
class ZmienneClass extends ChangeNotifier {
void decrementCounter(int liczba) {
      if (_rundy == 0) {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => resGamePage(title: "")));
      };}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BuildContext` is needed to tell Flutter where it should build its widgets. Currently you are trying to access a `context` without actually providing a valid `BuildContext`, if you really want to access the `context`, you could provide it trough the `decrementCounter` by passing one more parameter in it, `decrementCounter(int liczba, BuildContext context)` and pass the context from where you are calling it.

Comment: Okey, error dissapeared, but now when _rundy are 0 nothing happens, can u help me with it? question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996718/switching-beetwen-sites-using-flutter

Answer (score 3):

You dont declare BuildContext try below code refer BuildContext [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html)

```
class ZmienneClass extends ChangeNotifier {

void decrementCounter(int liczba,BuildContext context) {
      if (_rundy == 0) {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => resGamePage(title: "")));
      };}}
```

Comment: Okey, error dissapeared, but when _rundy are 0 nothing happens, can u help me with it? question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996718/switching-beetwen-sites-using-flutter