# Switching beetwen sites using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, navigator

Flutter don't show any error, just if ***_rundy = 0*** page doesn't switch, 0 reaction. ZmienneClass is class for variables, not any Page which is showing on application. I guess it may be problem with Buildcontext but idk, im beginner with flutter. (ResultPage is resGamePage)

```
class ZmienneClass extends ChangeNotifier {
 void decrementCounter(int liczba, BuildContext context) {
      if (_rundy == 0) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => resGamePage(title: "Wyniki")));
  void setPlayerCount({required int liczbagraczy}) {
    graczepoczatkowi = liczbagraczy;}
  }}}
```

Some resGamePage code

```
class resGamePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const resGamePage({Key? key, value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _resGamePageState createState() => _resGamePageState();
}

class _resGamePageState extends State<resGamePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ZmienneClass())],
        child: Scaffold(
```

[image: Widget Tree]

Answer (score 1):

You can use push replacement command

```
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                    context,
                                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => Disconnect()));
```

Where **Disconnect** is the name of your next page stless widget

This code does destroys the current activity and then it loads the next activity
You can use it to go to any page as you said in above diagram

If you are in the FirGamePage then you can go to the SecGamePage by this command by a button click or as per your UI

Hope this solution helps **;)**

Comment: Unfortunately pages still don't switch.

Comment: Can you please specify what do you mean by switch and send your code here also please do like my above solution it would be my pleasure

Comment: when user is looking at screen, and the value is 0, user should instantly see another "picture" / "scene" / "view" of application. sorry but i am pretty bad at explaining things like this :c